# Is there a React Native framework for compressing image size?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am newbie with react native, so i'm trying to create a React Native app which a lot of people may upload more than 5 photos so in few words "Database could get out of space quicker, photos are gonna last longer to upload on others user screen".

**What is the most recommended way for resizing and compressing images on react native app?**

**Is Facebook Spectrum available for react native?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this link : 
https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-resizer

A React Native module that can create scaled versions of local images (also supports the assets library on iOS).

It allows you to specify:
Max dimensions (whilst preserving aspect ratio) and;
Output quality (for JPEG only)

**OR**

Refer this link : 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-compress-image

Is Facebook Spectrum available for react native?
Refer this link:
https://www.facebook.com/fbOpenSource/posts/we-are-proud-to-launch-spectrum-a-cross-platform-image-transcoding-library-that-/1918840864831332/

Comment: Thanks, but when it says "Output quality (for JPEG only)" it only means that it is going to export to JPEG file extension?

Comment: quality:A number between 0 and 100. Used for the JPEG compression.
Check this link:https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-resizer/issues/159